# What do packed_to_unpacked blocks do in GNU RADIO?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Could somebody give me an example(e.g. input->output) of what this block does? Explanation is also appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done so far? There is documentation on functions similar to what you specified here: https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the official documentation](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1blocks_1_1packed__to__unpacked__bb.html) (which, if your GNU Radio build is intact, you can also access from the documentation tab of your block properties in GRC):

> Convert a stream of packed bytes or shorts to stream of unpacked bytes or shorts.
>
> input: stream of unsigned char; output: stream of unsigned char
>
> This is the inverse of gr::blocks::unpacked_to_packed_XX.
>
> The bits in the bytes or shorts input stream are grouped into chunks of bits_per_chunk bits and each resulting chunk is written right- justified to the output stream of bytes or shorts. All b or 16 bits of the each input bytes or short are processed. The right thing is done if bits_per_chunk is not a power of two.
>
> The combination of gr::blocks::packed_to_unpacked_XX_ followed by gr_chunks_to_symbols_Xf or gr_chunks_to_symbols_Xc handles the general case of mapping from a stream of bytes or shorts into arbitrary float or complex symbols.

so, you get a byte in, consisting of 8 bits, and you produce bytes, each of one with `bits_per_chunk` bits set according to the input. Example (let `bits_per_chunk=1`, MSB first):

```
in 0b11110000
out 0b00000001 0b00000001 0b00000001 0b00000001 0b00000000 0b00000000 0b00000000 0b00000000
```